# Couldn't use different version of firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have 2 firefox versions installed in my system. They are version 61.0b.10 and version 44.0.2. I normally use version 61.0b.10 to practice selenium. I was trying to learn to launch different version of firefox. So, I was trying to launch firefox version 44.0.2. I have used the below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\Firefox - Old\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and also the below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\Firefox - Old\\firefox.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", "false");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(capabilities);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Both result in launching the firefox version 61.0b.10.

I have also tried the below code.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Firefox - Old\\firefox.exe")));
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

This code is giving me the exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: My question is how to run 2 versions of firefox. Now about driver.

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor change. Use webdriver.firefox.bin property

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Users\\user\\Firefox - Old\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Getting the exception: SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.

Comment: are you sure you're using correct selenium version with firefox 44.0 ?

Comment: I'm using v 3.8.1

Comment: you can't use 3.8.1 with firefox 44.0. I think you need v2.52 for running wih firefox 44.0.

Comment: Why? Should I be using firefox version 48 or higher with GeckoDriver?

Comment: @learningQA - yes give it a try